# When is a Sylow $p$-subgroup normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $A_5$ be the alternating group of degree 5. I would like to prove that the number $s_5$ of Sylow 5-subgroups of $A_5$ ist 6. With $|A_5| = \frac{5!}{2} = 60 = 5 \cdot 12$ and the Sylow theorems I get that 12 is a multiple of $s_5$ and $s_5 = 1 + 5k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Therefore $s_5 \in \{1,6\}$. I could exclude the case $s_5 = 1$ by finding at least two Sylow 5-subgroups of $A_5$, but it is enough to show that a Sylow 5-subgroup of $A_5$ is not normal. Unfortunately, I don't see how this is apparent.

1. How can be shown that a Sylow 5-subgroup of $A_5$ is not normal?
2. How does the answer for (1) generalize for groups other than $A_5$?

Comment: Perhaps I am stating the obvious and/or cheating, but it is possible that a question asking you to reason about how many Sylow $5$-subgroups there are in $A_5$ expects you to know and exploit the fact that $A_5$ is simple, which tells you immediately that such a subgroup cannot be normal.

Comment: A Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if it is the *only* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. This follows from the Sylow Theorems, which say that if $P$ and $Q$ are any two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, then they are conjugate: there exists $g\in G$ such that $gPg^{-1}=Q$. So if $P\neq Q$, this shows $P$ cannot be normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. elements of $A_5$ are totally explicit.  5-Sylow are  cyclic of order $5$ , generated by a $5$-cycle. So, pick for example $s=(1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4 \ 5)$ . I am pretty sure that if you pick a random element $t$ of $A_5$, $tst^{-1}$ won't be a power of $s$.
2. You cannot expect a general reasonable answer( except the trivial one: given a subgroup  $H$ of $G$, compute $gHg^{-1}$ ofr all $g\in G$ and see if it is contained in $H$. Of course you can use generators of $H$ and/or $G$ to reduce to a small number of verifications, but still...)

To prove my point: any group $G$ with odd order has a non trivial normal subgroup. I really doubt that if I give you a group $G$ of huge odd order and a subgroup $H$, you will be able to decide if $H$ is normal or not.

Proving that a given group does or does not have a nontrivial normal subgroup is difficult. For example, the classification of finite simple groups took decades of efforts, and involves extremely difficult mathematics.